# Calling User Nickname

Tags: users, username

I am currently calling a user's nicename in a function I have:

```
$users = $user_query->get_results();
foreach( $users as $user ):
echo $user->user_nicename;
```

I'm trying to call the user's Nickname instead, but nothing I do is working such as:

```
echo $user->user_nickname;
```

Is there a special way you have to call a user's nickname?

Thanks

Comment: What does `$user_query->get_results()` return?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
echo the_author_meta( 'nickname', $current_user->ID );
```

or you can also use;

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $current_user->nickname;
```

Comment: Please explain how to use this with the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query *all* users, try using the [**`get_users()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function. Note that this function returns an **array**:

```
<?php
$users = get_users();

foreach( $users as $user ) {
    echo $user['user_nicename'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I have a custom code that provides a list of users based on certain criteria, but I am just not able to successfully call (and display) the user's nickname instead of their nicename.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer/help, without seeing this "custom code"?

Comment: I didn't think the code itself was really relevant, I was just asking in general for how to call a user's nickname.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. :) If the code itself isn't really relevant, why did you bring it up?

Comment: I think I'm confused too... ;) Your original reply mentioned querying all users, which I am not doing. I am just trying to change the way my query displays on my page (using nickname instead of nicename) so that a user's first and last name will appear.

Comment: But in order to help you figure out how to *change* your current query, we need to know *how you're currently querying* - which is why we need to see your query code. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to answer without seeing your code but there is no [`user_nickname` in the `$wpdb->users` table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) and no `user_nickname` key in the `$wpdb->usermeta` table by default.

Assuming that `$users` is a user object then:

```
$users = $user_query->get_results();  
foreach( $users as $user ) {  
   echo get_user_meta($user->ID,'nickname',true); 
}
```

Should get you the user nickname.